# Which files have good compression ratio using textbook's Huffman coding algorithm?

Tags: java, performance, file, huffman-code

I am testing Huffman coding now, and I wanted to know which type of files(like .txt, .jpg, .mp3 etc) experience a good compression when they undergo Huffman based compression. I implemented Huffman coding in java and I found out that I was getting about 40% size reduction for .txt files(the ones with ordinary English text) and about almost 0% - 1% reduction on .jpg, .mp3, and .mp4 files (of course I haven't tested it on huge files above 1 MB, because my program is super slow). I understand that Huffman coding works best for those files which have more frequently occurring symbols, however I do not know what kind of symbols are there in a video, audio or an image file, hence the question. Since that I have designed this program(I did it for my project at school, I will not deny it, I did it on my own and I am only asking for a few pointers for my research), I wanted to know where it would work well.

Thanks.

Note: I initially created this project only for .txt files and to my wonder, it was working on all other types of files as well, hence I wanted to test it and thereby I had to ask this question. I found out that for image files, you don't encode the symbols themselves, but rather some RGB values? Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about the amount of redundancy in the file.

In any file each byte occupies 8 bits, allowing 256 distinct symbols per byte.  In a text file, a relatively small number of those symbols are actually used, and the distribution of the symbols is not flat (there are more `e`s than `q`s).  Thus the information "density" is more like 5 bits per byte.

JPEGs, MP3 and MP4 are already compressed and have almost no redundancy.  All 256 symbols are used, with about equal frequency, so the information "density" is very close to 8 bits per byte.  You cannot compress it further.

Comment: Oh I see why I was getting almost no compression on video, audio, image files. Apart from text files, are there any other files Huffman algorithm is better at?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think Huffman coding is "optimal" for any kind of data – data is data after all, just a sequence of bytes. So I don't think it's as if Huffman coding were not effective for video, audio or images: it's simply already done at some point after the lossy part of the compression for the data formats you're likely considering.